# How can a mocked method be called and not be detected by spy?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine, spy

Here's my Component :

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-signup',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
    specialLink: string;

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
        this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
        console.log('TEST1', this.specialLink);

        if (this.specialLink !== undefined) {
            this.setSpecialSignup();
        }
    }

    setSpecialSignup() {
        console.log("CALLED;");
    }
```

And here's my tests :

```js
describe('SignUpComponent', () => {
  let component: SignUpComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignUpComponent>;
  let ActivatedRouteMock: any;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    ActivatedRouteMock = {
      snapshot: {
        params: { id: 123 }
      },
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SignUpComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteMock}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignUpComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });


  describe('Patient Side', () => {
    it('should call setSpecialSignup() when user is coming from specialLink', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'setSpecialSignup');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.setSpecialSignup).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I'm testing if setSpecialSignup has been called. And it is ! The 2 'console.log' prove it. Then, why do I get this error : `Expected spy setSpecialSignup to have been called.`?
What did I miss ?

It looks like I need to be able to change the value of ActivatedRouteMock.snapshot.params.id. Sometimes it has to be undefined and sometimes it has to be 'something'. How can I do that ? I tried `ActivatedRouteMock.snapshot.params.id = 'something'` but it doesn't change the value at all, even with fixture.detectChanges(). How can I do that ?

Comment: Probably you're spying too late. But don't spy on the thing you're actually trying to test - test doubles are for *collaborators*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On what should I spy then ?

Comment: That depends on what `setSpecialSignup` *actually* does.

Comment: Set some variables and get an data from DB (Firebase)

Comment: Then the test double should be the injected service via which it's accessing Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as we see `setSpecialSignup` is called inside of a `constructor`. `constructor` is called on this line `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SignUpComponent);`. and you create a spy too late. if you want this feature to be testable easier, move logic of your component to `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. it will be called on the first `fixture.detectChanges()` and your test should be fine

```
constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
        console.log('TEST1', this.specialLink);

        if (this.specialLink !== undefined) {
            this.setSpecialSignup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation ! Since I need to test this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id; do you know how I can change the 'id' value in ActivatedRouteMock in my tests ?

Comment: here you fully redefine your route mock ` ActivatedRouteMock = ...` and you define it as 123 `params: { id: 123 }`. change it to whatever you like before first `detectChanges()`.

Comment: I added `ActivatedRouteMock = { snapshot: { params: { id: 123 } }, };` before the very first detectChanges() but i doesn't work.

Comment: I mean the value changed yes. But since the value is not undefined, setSpecialSignup should have been called and I get the error again : `Expected spy setSpecialSignup to have been called.`

Comment: you can do `ActivatedRouteMock.snapshot.params.id = null;` in the test where you want to test it with null value.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is a option, but I have 99 tests where `ActivatedRouteMock.snapshot.params.id = null;`and only 1 where it is not. So I prefer to do this the other way around. So I manage to get `ActivatedRouteMock.snapshot.params.id = 'something';` and even `component.specialLink = 'something';` too but when I `fixture.detectChanges()`it doesn't call setSpecialSignup function. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Can you move the code that you put in the constructor to ngOnInit()

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-signup',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
    specialLink: string;

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {
       
    }
ngOnInit(){
 this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
        console.log('TEST1', this.specialLink);

        if (this.specialLink !== undefined) {
            this.setSpecialSignup();
        }
}

    setSpecialSignup() {
        console.log("CALLED;");
    }
```

Can you please try the below code?

```
describe('SignUpComponent', () => {
  let component: SignUpComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SignUpComponent>;
  let ActivatedRouteMock: any;
  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    ActivatedRouteMock = {
      snapshot: {
        params: { id: 123 }
      },
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SignUpComponent ],
      imports: [ RouterTestingModule ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: ActivatedRouteMock}
      ]
    })
  .compileComponents().then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PriceModelListComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;         
        });
  }));

 
  describe('Patient Side', () => {
    it('should call setSpecialSignup() when user is coming from specialLink', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'setSpecialSignup');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.setSpecialSignup).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

**For mocking params**

Inside the provider in spec

```
providers: [ { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { // Mock queryParams: of( { id_params: 'id_params_test' } ), params: of( { id_query_params: 'id_query_params_test' } ) } } ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it is not working. There are no changes.

Comment: .compileComponents().then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PriceModelListComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;         
        });

Comment: can you move that function from constructor to ngOnInit()?

Comment: It works now thanks. Since I need to test `this.specialLink = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;` do you know how I can change the 'id' value in ActivatedRouteMock in my tests ?